# How to merge two Objects using javascript?

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
a = {
    coffee: 'Coffees',
    mango: '10 Mangos',
    shoe: '2 Shoes',
    bag: '5 Bags',
    abc: 'D E F'
}

b = {
    coffee,
    abc,
    bag,
}


mergerd_output_will_be = {
    coffee: 'Coffees',
    abc: 'D E F',
    bag: '5 Bags'
}
```

How can I merger 'a' object like this?
'b' object key will be included only outputted object.

Comment: In your code example, "b" is not a valid JavaScript object.

Comment: Why is this tagged PHP and Laravel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Surely ES6+ must have a way to merge two javascript objects together, what is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852852/surely-es6-must-have-a-way-to-merge-two-javascript-objects-together-what-is-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to get intersection of keys of two objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34392741/best-way-to-get-intersection-of-keys-of-two-objects)

Comment: @cgTag I think it's shorthand property names (ES2015). It's a valid example

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and construct an object with each key value.

```js
    let a = {
        coffee: 'Coffees',
        mango: '10 Mangos',
        shoe: '2 Shoes',
        bag: '5 Bags',
        abc: 'D E F'
    }
    let b = {'coffee':null, 'abc':null, 'bag':null};
    let c = Object.keys(b).reduce((current,key)=>({...current, [key]:a[key]}), {});
    console.log(c);
```

Comment: How to merge **two Objects** using javascript?

Comment: @kemicofa what is the second object and it's values? How can I answer it then?

Comment: just upvoted so cool, but I am a big fan of shorthands (even if just syntactic sugar), so what about: `let c = Object.keys(b).reduce((current, key) => ({ ...current, [key]: a[key] }), {});`

Comment: @quirimmo ah, I was trying to figure that out. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You [`_.pick()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#pick) from object `a` the [`_.keys()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#pick) of object `b`:

```js
const a = {
  coffee: 'Coffees',
  mango: '10 Mangos',
  shoe: '2 Shoes',
  bag: '5 Bags',
  abc: 'D E F'
}

const b = {
  coffee: null,
  abc: null,
  bag: null
}

const result = _.pick(a, _.keys(b))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Initial code that you've provided is invalid (variable b)

You can make something like this:

```js
const a = {
    coffee: 'Coffees',
    mango: '10 Mangos',
    shoe: '2 Shoes',
    bag: '5 Bags',
    abc: 'D E F'
}

const props = ['coffee', 'abc', 'bag'];

const mergerd_output_will_be = {};
props.forEach(propName => mergerd_output_will_be[propName] = a[propName]);
```

or

```js
const a = {
    coffee: 'Coffees',
    mango: '10 Mangos',
    shoe: '2 Shoes',
    bag: '5 Bags',
    abc: 'D E F'
}

const b = {coffee: null, abc: null, bag: null};

const mergerd_output_will_be = {...b};
Object.keys(mergerd_output_will_be).forEach(propName => 
  mergerd_output_will_be[propName]=a[propName]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

basically you have 2 ways, using `... spread operator` or `Object.assign()`

```js
const coffee = 'Coffees'
const abc = 'abc';
const bag = 'bag'

const a = {
  coffee: 'Coffees',
  mango: '10 Mangos',
  shoe: '2 Shoes',
  bag: '5 Bags',
  abc: 'D E F'
}

const b = {
  coffee,
  abc,
  bag,
}

const result1 = {...a, ...b};
const result2 = Object.assign({}, a, b)

console.log(result1)
console.log(result2)
```

Comment: the answer does not seem to be right because the OP wants an intersection of 2 objects instead of a union. The merged_object in the description contains only the common fields. Your answer will merge both objects.

Comment: @HussainAliAkbar totally right, I did not get the question of the OP properly and I even upvoted this answer. Now I cannot even remove my upvote -.-
By the way, let's say that the title is unclear, because "merge" two objects means what this answer says

Comment: yup you are right the title is unclear. What the OP wants is the intersection of 2 objects and not "merge".

Answer (score 0):

First, an Object should be Key-value Pairs in it, for this  you can change b to array such as b = ['coffee', 'D E F', '5 Bags']

Then, use the below code to produce the expected output.

```
let a = {
  coffee: 'Coffees',
  mango: '10 Mangos',
  shoe: '2 Shoes',
  bag: '5 Bags',
  abc: 'D E F'
 };
 let b = ['coffee', 'abc', 'bag'];
let output = {};
for( let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
 output[b[i]] = a[b[i]];
}
```