# How do I merge two objects such that keys from one map to values of another, without the extra keys in the second, using latest Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

**Object A**:

```
 let form= {
      first_name: "",
      last_name: "",
      avatar: ""
}
```

**Object B**

```
 let profile {
      first_name: "John",
      last_name: "Doe",
      avatar: "https://image.cdn.com",
      ....100 other fields

}
```

Basically I should end up with:

```
newObject: {
      first_name: "John",
      last_name: "Doe",
      avatar: "https://image.cdn.com"
}
```

Without those extra items in the second object.

I tried this but it still returns the extra keys I don't want:

```
let profile= {
      first_name: "John",
      last_name: "Doe",
      avatar: "https://image.cdn.com",
      key1: 1,
      key2: 2,
      key: 3,

}
let form= {
      first_name: "",
      last_name: "",
      avatar: ""
}

console.log(_.merge(form, profile));
```

Comment: _“I tried this but it still returns the extra keys I don't want”_ - you don’t actually want a _merge_ to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab the keys from one object using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), then [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) these keys to an object, which uses the key from the map as the key for the object and the value from the other object for that given key as the value for the object. Then use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to build an object from this array of objects:

```js
const form = { first_name: "", last_name: "", avatar: "" };
const profile = { first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe", avatar: "https://image.cdn.com", foo: 1, bar: 2, foobar: 3 };

const lift = (o1, o2) => 
  Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(o1).map(k => ({[k]: o2[k]})));

const res = lift(form, profile);
console.log(res);
```

Or, since you're using [**lodash**](https://lodash.com/) in your example, you can use lodash's [`_.pick()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pick) method with [`_.keys()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#keys) like so:

```js
const form = { first_name: "", last_name: "", avatar: "" };
const profile = { first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe", avatar: "https://image.cdn.com", foo: 1, bar: 2, foobar: 3 };

const res = _.pick(profile, _.keys(form));
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `_.pick(profile, _.keys(form));` wins it for me. Bravo!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.keys()` and `Array.reduce()` to iterate over the object

```js
let form = {
  first_name: "",
  last_name: "",
  avatar: ""
}

let profile = {
  first_name: "John",
  last_name: "Doe",
  avatar: "https://image.cdn.com",
  dummy: 'Dummy'
}

let newObject = Object.keys(form).reduce((acc, key) => {
  acc[key] = profile[key];
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(newObject)
```

**UPDATE:**

With `lodash` you can do it as followings:

```js
let form = {
  first_name: "",
  last_name: "",
  avatar: ""
}

let profile = {
  first_name: "John",
  last_name: "Doe",
  avatar: "https://image.cdn.com",
  dummy: 'Dummy'
}

let intersection = _.intersection(Object.keys(form), Object.keys(profile))

console.log(intersection);

intersection.forEach(key => form[key] = profile[key])

console.log(form);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Looks good, trying to find the fastest way, however. Got a big object in here.

Comment: afaik, methods like `Array.reduce()`, `Array.map()` etc. are highly optimized. Therefore the performance of loop should not be a problem. Maybe you can try some benchmark sites

Comment: Thanks Harun. Any idea if I can achieve the same with lodash, just curious.

Comment: I just had a look at its documentation but could not find a built-in intersection method for objects. Btw, you can check this SO thread out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34392937/1331040

Comment: I updated the answer to accomplish the same with `_.intersection()` and `Object.keys()`. Hope this gives you a clue.

Comment: Thank you. Looks interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.assign()` or ES6 spread operator to create a new object

```js
let profile= {
      first_name: "John",
      last_name: "Doe",
      avatar: "https://image.cdn.com",
      key1: 1,
      key2: 2,
      key: 3,

}
let form= {
      first_name: "",
      last_name: "",
      avatar: ""
}

let output = { ...form, ...profile };

console.log(output);
```

And if you want to don't want to override the values in source object if value is not falsy/empty then you can do something like

```js
let profile= {
      first_name: "John",
      last_name: "Doe",
      avatar: "https://image.cdn.com",
      key1: 1,
      key2: 2,
      key: 3,

}
let form= {
      first_name: "Adam",
      last_name: "",
      avatar: ""
}

const output = Object.keys(form).reduce((prev, key) => {
  prev[key] = form[key] || profile[key];
  return prev;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: That still has all the extra keys in the result, that they _don’t_ want.

Comment: Nope, I actually don't want a merge. This does a merge.

Comment: @AliGajani  I updated the answer , see the second part

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is creating your own merging function (but to check your real need..
e.g. if on form variable an attributes is not empty.. which value will win ? but you can adjust my example according 
e.g.

```
function getOnlyExisting(aParam1, aParam2) {
    var vResult = Object.create(aParam1);
    for (var vAttributeName in aParam1) {
        if (aParam2.hasOwnProperty(vAttributeName)) {
            vResult[vAttributeName] = aParam2[vAttributeName];
        }
    }
    return vResult;
}

let profile = {
    first_name: "John",
    last_name: "Doe",
    avatar: "https://image.cdn.com",
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
    key: 3,

}
let form = {
    first_name: "",
    last_name: "",
    avatar: ""
}

console.log(getOnlyExisting(form, profile));
```